# disable button in view until value is entered into field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Using a numeric keypad to pass back a value to the POST. If the input field is left empty and the user clicks the 'Order' button 'webiste can not display' error appears.

I would like to disable to 'order' button until a value is entered into the input field.

any help appreciated:

```
     <table class="ui-bar-a" id="n_keypad" style="float: right;">
        <tr>
           <td><a data-role="button" data-theme="b" class="numero">7</a></td>
           <td><a data-role="button" data-theme="b" class="numero">8</a></td>
           <td><a data-role="button" data-theme="b" class="numero">9</a></td>
           <td><a data-role="button" data-theme="e" class="del">Del</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td><a data-role="button" data-theme="b" class="numero">4</a></td>
           <td><a data-role="button" data-theme="b" class="numero">5</a></td>
           <td><a data-role="button" data-theme="b" class="numero">6</a></td>
           <td><a data-role="button" data-theme="e" class="clear">Clear</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td><a data-role="button" data-theme="b" class="numero">1</a></td>
           <td><a data-role="button" data-theme="b" class="numero">2</a></td>
           <td><a data-role="button" data-theme="b" class="numero">3</a></td>
           <td><a data-role="button" data-theme="e" class="switch">+/-</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td><a data-role="button" data-theme="e" class="neg">-</a></td>
           <td><a data-role="button" data-theme="b" class="zero">0</a></td>
           <td><a data-role="button" data-theme="e" class="pos">+</a></td>
           <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />

    <p><button type="submit" name="command" value="Save" style="float: right;">Order</button></p>

</fieldset>
}

        <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.numero').click(function () {
                if (!isNaN($('#myInput').val())) {
                    if (parseInt($('#myInput').val()) == 0) {
                        $('#myInput').val($(this).text());
                    } else {
                        $('#myInput').val($('#myInput').val() + $(this).text());
                    }
                }
            });
            $('.neg').click(function () {
                if (!isNaN($('#myInput').val()) && $('#myInput').val().length > 0) {
                        $('#myInput').val(parseInt($('#myInput').val()) - 1);
                }
            });
            $('.pos').click(function () {
                if (!isNaN($('#myInput').val()) && $('#myInput').val().length > 0) {
                    $('#myInput').val(parseInt($('#myInput').val()) + 1);
                }
            });
            $('.del').click(function () {
                $('#myInput').val($('#myInput').val().substring(0, $('#myInput').val().length - 1));
            });
            $('.clear').click(function () {
                $('#myInput').val('');
            });
            $('.zero').click(function () {
                if (!isNaN($('#myInput').val())) {
                    if (parseInt($('#myInput').val()) != 0) {
                        $('#myInput').val($('#myInput').val() + $(this).text());
                    }
                }
            });
            $('.switch').click(function () {
                var $input = $('#myInput');
                $input.val() != "" && !isNaN($input.val()) && $input.val(-$input.val());
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Your HTML code has no `input` fields? While it's good to validate the input on the client side, but you should also do it server side in case someone has javascript turned off, as they would still see your 'website cannot display' error page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your order button an id, and when changing the input value to enable it:

```
$("#order-button").removeAttr('disabled');
```

and to disable it again use:

```
$("#order-button").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Also server side validation is always a good backup to have